# Free Cloud storage provider with an API WITHOUT oauth?

Tags: c#, .net, backup, cloud, cloud-storage

Anybody knows a  **FREE** (some free volme, 2-5 GB i mean - continuously, not just the first year like Amazon S3) cloud storage provider which has an API that does **NOT** use oauth ?

I need that to make regular backups to from a console service (scheduled web-browser and user-input free application).

I have looked at DropBox, Google Drive, SkyDrive and UbuntuOne.
DropBox & Google use oAuth, which I can't use (oAuth is **NOT** web-browser & user input free).
UbuntuOne's "API" is a horrible mess - simply unusable.
SkyDrive SDK needs Windows. I have my data on a Linux server, and that's not gonna change.

Comment: You can access SkyDrive over WebDAV, would that work for you?

Comment: @Kevin: Hmm interesting. Yes, I think WebDAV is possible on Linux with C#/mono.

Comment: You don't even need your code to handle the WebDAV part. Just mount the WebDAV share and then your code can just pretend it's a local folder.

Comment: FREE for life without any benefits? Oh yes, I want free food, free medicines, free traveling. Come on, they are not charging millions, they are charging in cents.

Comment: [Parse](https://parse.com) gives you 1GB storage for free.